# S-curve in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}    
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum,makecell,amsmath}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=north west,
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                                /pgf/number format/precision=1},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                                /pgf/number format/precision=1},
            grid = major,
            width=10cm,
            height=8cm,
            grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            xmin=0,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
            xmax= 1,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
            ymin= 0,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
            ymax= 1,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
            %axis background/.style={fill=white},
            xlabel=$s$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            tick align=outside,
            enlargelimits=false]
          % plot the stirling-formulae
          \path[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,0);
          \path[name path=B] (0,1) -- (1,1);
          \addplot[domain=0:1, red, ultra thick,samples=500,name path=C] {1-(1-x^3)^6};
          \addlegendentry{$f(s)=(1-(1-s^4)^5$}
          \addplot [green!50!black] fill between [
            of=A and C,
            soft clip={domain=0:0.5}];
          \addplot [blue!50] fill between [
            of=B and C,
            soft clip={domain=0.5:1}];
          \draw[thick] (0.5,1) -- (0.5,0);
          \end{axis}
          \path (current axis.south) node[below,anchor=north] {$t$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When i Run the code i get the following:

[image]

Comment: There is no photo.

Comment: @marmot oups i added it

Comment: i know it's not what you want, but it looks like a very nice cartoon of a wading bird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can do that with `fillbetween'.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=north west,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        grid = major,
        width=10cm,
        height=8cm,
        grid style={dashed, gray!30},
        xmin=0,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
        xmax= 1,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
        ymin= 0,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
        ymax= 1,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
        %axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xlabel=$s$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        tick align=outside,
        enlargelimits=false]
      % plot the stirling-formulae
      \path[name path=A] (0,0) -- (1,0);
      \path[name path=B] (0,1) -- (1,1);
      \addplot[domain=0:1, red, ultra thick,samples=500,name path=C] {1-(1-x^3)^6};
      \addlegendentry{$f(s)=(1-(1-s^4)^5$}
      \addplot [green!50!black] fill between [
        of=A and C,
        soft clip={domain=0:0.5}];
      \addplot [blue!50] fill between [
        of=B and C,
        soft clip={domain=0.5:1}];
      \draw[thick] (0.5,1) -- (0.5,0);
      \end{axis}
      \path (current axis.south) node[below,anchor=north] {$t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but how can i add t in the axis line

Comment: ineed please t to be the label of the line.

Comment: @bib Better now?

Comment: the update give a wrong picture

Comment: i still get a wrong image, sorry

Comment: i get the green color above the curve. I just added \path (current axis.south) node[below,anchor=north] {$t$}; on your first update and i get the result i need. Thank you so so much :)

Comment: sorry again. I think you upload a wrong code. I try to use the first upload you did. I can find t under the x -axis but i cant see the verticle line at t. can you please recheck your modified code you upload, I tried to use this code with the class elastic for my paper

Comment: i edited my original post. so i put what i get when i run your code. Im using overleaf website to do my paper.

Comment: You are the best. The pb was just in overleaf and with the elsarticle class. It accept only \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} and not 1.16 (i dont know why). Thank you again for your great support. your code run as expected